# Java script Remove items from local storage when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a number of diary entries on my web page and if you click the x button then it deletes the entry from the web page just fine but i also need the X button to remove the item from storage using the key.

I have tried using the following but i'm sure i'm missing something simple.

```
function addSection(key, element) {
// Create a section element to contain the new entry
var sectionElement = document.createElement("section");

// Give the section a class to allow styling
sectionElement.classList.add("entry");

// Add the element to the section
sectionElement.appendChild(element);

// Create a button to delete the entry
var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
deleteButton.innerHTML = "&times;";
deleteButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "Delete entry");

// Create an event listener to delete the entry
function deleteEntry() {
    // Remove the section from the page
    sectionElement.parentNode.removeChild(sectionElement);

    // Remove the item from local storage by key
    
    localStorage.removeItem("Key");
}
```

Any help on this matter would be really appricated it. I'm hitting a brick wall and nothing else i try is working.

Comment: You should pass key either in the function parameter or get it from the button clicked... and then just use that key to remove it from localStorage.

Comment: How do you store the value in `localStorage`?

Comment: I have edited the code above to show more of the function

Comment: @MuhammadZaib i have added more code above to see if this helps how my functions are working

Comment: @Shuvo please see the above edits

Comment: What is the `key` here: `localStorage.removeItem("Key");`?

Comment: @JuniorJavaDev you can try localStorage.removeItem(key);

Comment: as per your code, it seems you are trying to keep the reference of sectionElement from the addSection element... which is not required.. and not recommended.And just a side note, you could've remove the sectionElement by just saying sectionElement.remove();
and use localStorage.removeItem(key)...